# update table using SQL INSERT not working in Flask App

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

So I have searched through existing questions based on my challenge and I haven't found any solution. I need help with updating a database by inserting a new value into a column that was hitherto null during the creation of the table. The code below is a route for profile. The first thing it does is to check if it the user that signed in. If not the user, the user is redirected to a login page. However, if it is the user I want the user to select a value from a drop-down list and then add the value to the users' table where the country column is set initially to NULL.  Currently, it is not adding the record to the database. On selection of the value, the value is not updated in the database. The country column I am trying to update remains null/empty

**APP.PY**

```py
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def profile():
    form = CountryForm(request.form) # A drop down list from where user select a value
    first = request.form.get('country_select')
    if not g.user:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
            try:
                with sqlite3.connect("tour.db") as con:
                    cur = con.cursor()
                    print("Opened database successfully")
                    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (country) VALUE (?)",(first) )
                    con.commit()
                    flash("Record successfully added")
            except:
                con.rollback()
                flash("error in insert operation")
            
            finally:
                return render_template("profile.html", msg = first)
                con.close()
    return render_template('profile.html', user=get_curr_user(), form=form, country=first)
```

**profile.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head %}
    <title>Profile Page</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <h1 class="title">
      Welcome, {{g.user.username}} 
  </h1>
  <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('profile') }}">
     <select name="country_select">
       {% for x in form.country %}
           <option>{{ x }}</option>
       {% endfor %}                                              
     </select>
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
 <p>{{country}}</p>
  <div class="auth-wrapper">
    <a href="{{url_for('logout')}}">Log out</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<html>
<body onload="brython(1)">
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <p>{{ message }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% block body %} {% endblock %}
    <script type=”text/python” src=”script/program.py”></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Looking forward to your contributions. Thanks.

Comment: It could be many things but have you verified that form.validate() is True ? Add a few prints in your code to see how far execution goes. Review the definition of CountryForm.

Comment: form.validate() is True. I did try printing out somethings but I do not get anything printed on the python terminal. This is how I did: I inserted `print(first)` within the route and the I run `python app.py` on my terminal and all I get to see is that everything is working fine and not print of `first` at this terminal, this is my definition of CountryForm: `class CountryForm(Form):  
    country = SelectField(label='Country', choices=COUNTRY)
`

Comment: Update: I found out that form.validate() will always return FALSE because there is no form of validation for that form. So I removed it. But now the current error I get now is `error in insert operation` which is the error that should be flashed when the insert operation is not successful. This is where I need help.

Comment: Surely the error message has got to be more descriptive than that ? Print the value of 'first' before doing the insert, what does it look like ? Since you have exception handling, you should take advantage of it and dump the full stracktrace. Have a look at Traceback Examples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html), you just have to add a few lines of code.